# stdout.write() in Dart has apparently been altered from sync to async, but how can I use it?

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I'm using stdout.write() in a number of places in Dart so as not to go to a new line. It was working OK, but has been changed recently from sync to async. I've just upgraded to Dart 28355 on Win7-32 and Win8-64.

The following describes the change:

"What changes?
Writes to stdout and stderr used to be blocking, on all platforms. As part of a cleanup, this is now async/non-blocking as any other Streams in dart:io.
How do I update my code?
Most code should work just like it used to, except a few cases when calling 'exit':"

A small example of what I would like to achieve is as follows:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  String sCorrectYn;
  while (sCorrectYn != "y") {
    String sName = fInputString("Enter Name : ");     
    sCorrectYn = fInputString("Details Correct? (y/n) : ");
  }
}

String fInputString(String sPrompt) {
  stdout.write("\n$sPrompt");
  return stdin.readLineSync().toLowerCase();
}
```

Terminal output when running the above on win8 is as follows:

```
c:\Users\boh\dart-dev1\testpg001>dart testinput001.dart

Enter Name : abcd
n
xxxx
n
zzzz
y

Details Correct? (y/n) :
Enter Name :
Details Correct? (y/n) :
Enter Name :
Details Correct? (y/n) :
c:\Users\boh\dart-dev1\testpg001>
```

What occurs with the above is that all of the terminal output appears after I finally enter "y", which terminates the program and flushes the output buffer (it appears). The first terminal output "Enter Name : " is the only output that occurs when it should.

It appears that there is no "flush" method for stdout.

I did experiment using stdout with a future, but I couldn't get it to function correctly.

How can I get this to work in the way needed?

The following also did not work as needed using stdout.write() :

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  String sInput;
  stdout.write("\nEntry 1 : ");
  sInput = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Date Entered (1) was : $sInput");  
  stdout.write("\nEntry 2 : ");  
  sInput = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Date Entered (2) was : $sInput");  
  stdout.write("\nEntry 3 : ");
  sInput = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Date Entered (3) was : $sInput");  
  stdout.write("\nEntry 4 : ");
  sInput = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Date Entered (4) was : $sInput");   
  stdout.write("\nEntry 5 : ");
  sInput = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Date Entered (5) was : $sInput");   
}
```

Terminal display for above shows 1st line "Entry 1 : " is only line displayed when required when using stdout.write() :

```
c:\Users\boh\dart-dev1\testpg001>dart testinput003.dart

Entry 1 : aaa
Date Entered (1) was : aaa
bbb
Date Entered (2) was : bbb
ccc
Date Entered (3) was : ccc
ddd
Date Entered (4) was : ddd
eee
Date Entered (5) was : eee

Entry 2 :
Entry 3 :
Entry 4 :
Entry 5 :
c:\Users\boh\dart-dev1\testpg001>
```

Comment: Your while loop is preventing anything asynchronous from happening. You really need to switch to future in that case. Please show what you tried with futures.

Comment: I tried without a loop, and the result was the same. No output from stdout.write() other than the first line, until the program terminated. I had no luck with Future, and I don't know if there is a solution there or not, there didn't appear to be to me. I would appreciate it if someone can illustrate how to make it work, because I need it to work together with input (readLineSync()). I need to handle input of successive responses to prompts.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to "flush" a `IOSink` can be implemented by using a `StreamController` to create a new `Stream` that can be waited for. I've rewritten your example above, using a `writeAndFlush` helper method.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  void loop() {
    fInputString("Enter Name : ")
      .then((_) => fInputString("Details Correct? (y/n) : "))
      .then((sCorrectYn) {
        if (sCorrectYn != "y") loop();
      });
  }
  loop();
}

Future<String> fInputString(String sPrompt) {
  return writeAndFlush(stdout, "\n$sPrompt")
    .then((_) {
      return stdin.readLineSync().toLowerCase();
    });
}

Future writeAndFlush(IOSink sink, object) {
  return sink.addStream(
    (new StreamController()
      ..add(UTF8.encode(object.toString()))
      ..close())
      .stream);
}
```

Adding a `flush` to IOSink, that does exactly this, is an option we should consider.

Note that this is actually not 'flushing' on an IO level, but it will wait for the `Stream` to be read to end, that is, waiting for the `Stream` to potentially be paused and resumed by the OS.

Comment: This is as I see it, so correct me if I'm wrong. While this answer solves the basic problem and is simple to implement in a small test program, it turns my program which was a synchronous program into an asynchronous program (terminal input) which (again) complicates it. In the past, the program used async input. Then from memory, readByteSync() was introduced, and then readLineSync(). That enabled the program to be made synchronous which simplified it. To change it back to asynchronous I believe illustrates that a sync write is needed for the terminal that doesn't output a newline.

Comment: . There is already the "print" statement that is synchronous, but it outputs a newline, which is not wanted when prompting for input. It appears to me while async write was I presume desirable, so is sync write, and we now have a sync read, but not a sync write without newline. I don't care what it's called, but I think I need it (sync write to console without newline).